# Laravel Backpack $guarded fields handling

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

As far as I understood (correct me if I am wrong), backpack only handles $fillable fields. Isn't the whole laravel thing is the separation between $fillable and $guarded?

MWE:

In the User.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $guarded = ['password'];
}
```

In the UserCrudController.php:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    $this->handlePasswordInput($request);
    return parent::updateCrud($request);
}
```

Will result in:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

While using 'strict' setting for MySQL, because 'password' field is $guarded.

Is there any proper workaround to separate $fillable and $guarded fields in Backpack?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use only one property, either guarded or fillable, $guarded represents blacklisted fields and $fillable represents whitelisted fields.

Comment: have you already check your password value from user input?

Comment: Yes, the password value is checked before

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using one - either $fillable or $guarded. I recommend using $fillable, it's more future-proof.

From the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent):

> While $fillable serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be
>   mass assignable, you may also choose to use $guarded. The $guarded
>   property should contain an array of attributes that you do not want to
>   be mass assignable. All other attributes not in the array will be mass
>   assignable. So, $guarded functions like a "black list". **Of course, you
>   should use either $fillable or $guarded - not both.**